# JavaScript constructor and tests

Tags: javascript

I am new in js, so it is maybe stupid question. I wrote this code, but test didn't pass.. I also was trying to pass test without any code in insert and contain, but test did'nt pass again. Tell me what's wrong with it?

```
'use strict';

class BinaryTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    insert(data) {
        // create new Node
        var newNode = new Node(data, null, null);

        // if tree is empty than make newNode as root
        if(this.root == null) {
            this.root = newNode;
        } else {
            // else find place where need to insert new node
            // start from root
            var currentNode = root;

            while(true) {
                // check: do we need to go left or right?
                // if left
                if(newNode.value < root.value) {
                    // if current left node is empty than insert newNode as current left node
                    if(currentNode.left == null) {
                        currentNode.left = newNode;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // else set current node as left current node
                        currentNode = currentNode.left;
                    }
                } else if(newNode.value > root.value) {
                    // if right

                    // if current right node is empty than insert newNode as current right node
                    if(currentNode.right == null) {
                        currentNode.right = newNode;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // else set current node as right current node
                        currentNode = currentNode.right;
                    }
                } else {
                    // if value already exist in tree than do nothing and break from while
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    contains(data) {
        var currentNode = this.root;
        var isFound = false;

        while (!isFound && currentNode != null){
            if(data < currentNode.value) {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            } else  if (data > currentNode.value) {
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            } else {
                isFound = true;
            }
        }

        return isFound;
    }

    remove(data) {

    }

    size() {

    }

    isEmpty() {

    }
}
```

test code:

```
var bt = new BinaryTree();
expect(bt.root).to.equal(null);
```

full test code:

```
var expectedBt = {
    root: {
        data: 13,
        left: {
            data: 10,
            left: {
                data: 8,
                left: {
                    data: 6,
                    left: null,
                    right: {
                        data: 7,
                        left: null,
                        right: null
                    }
                },
                right: null
            },
            right: {
                data: 12,
                left: {
                    data: 11,
                    left: null,
                    right: null
                },
                right: null
            }
        },
        right: {
            data: 18,
            left: {
                data: 15,
                left: null,
                right: null
            },
            right: {
                data: 20,
                left: null,
                right: null
            }
        }
    }
};

describe('BinaryTree', () => {
    describe('#constructor', () => {
        it('assigns null to root', () => {
            var bt = new BinaryTree();

            expect(bt.root).to.equal(null);
        });
    });

    describe('#insert(data)', () => {
        var bt;

        beforeEach(() => {
            bt = new BinaryTree();

            bt.insert(13);
            bt.insert(10);
            bt.insert(8);
            bt.insert(18);
            bt.insert(12);
            bt.insert(11);
            bt.insert(15);
            bt.insert(6);
            bt.insert(20);
            bt.insert(7);
        });

        it('creates new node with passed data and inserts it to correct place', () => {
            bt.root.data.should.equal(13);
            bt.root.left.data.should.equal(10);
            bt.root.right.data.should.equal(18);
            bt.root.left.left.data.should.equal(8);
            bt.root.left.right.data.should.equal(12);
            bt.root.right.left.data.should.equal(15);
            bt.root.right.right.data.should.equal(20);
            bt.root.left.left.left.data.should.equal(6);
            bt.root.left.left.left.right.data.should.equal(7);
            bt.root.left.right.left.data.should.equal(11);
        });
    });

    describe('#contains(data)', () => {
        var bt;

        beforeEach(() => {
            bt = new BinaryTree();

            bt.insert(13);
            bt.insert(10);
            bt.insert(8);
            bt.insert(18);
            bt.insert(12);
            bt.insert(11);
            bt.insert(15);
            bt.insert(6);
            bt.insert(20);
            bt.insert(7);
        });

        it('returns true if passed data found in binary tree, otherwise if not', () => {
            bt.contains(3).should.equal(false);
            bt.contains(9).should.equal(false);
            bt.contains(16).should.equal(false);

            bt.contains(18).should.equal(true);
            bt.contains(13).should.equal(true);
            bt.contains(7).should.equal(true);
            bt.contains(20).should.equal(true);
        });
    });

    describe('#remove(data)', () => {
        var bt;
        var btCopy;

        beforeEach(() => {
            bt = new BinaryTree();

            bt.insert(13);
            bt.insert(10);
            bt.insert(8);
            bt.insert(18);
            bt.insert(12);
            bt.insert(11);
            bt.insert(15);
            bt.insert(6);
            bt.insert(20);
            bt.insert(7);

            btCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expectedBt));
        });

        it('does nothing if passed data not found', () => {
            sinon.spy(bt, 'contains');

            bt.remove(9);
            bt.should.deep.equal(btCopy);
        });

        it('removes node which contains passed data', () => {
            sinon.spy(bt, 'contains');

            bt.remove(15);
            btCopy.root.right.left = null;

            bt.should.deep.equal(btCopy);

            bt.remove(8);
            btCopy.root.left.left = btCopy.root.left.left.left;

            bt.should.deep.equal(btCopy);
        });
    });

    describe('#size()', () => {
        it('returns number of elements in tree', () => {
            var bt = new BinaryTree();

            bt.size().should.equal(0);

            bt.insert(13);
            bt.insert(10);
            bt.insert(8);
            bt.insert(18);
            bt.insert(12);
            bt.insert(11);
            bt.insert(15);
            bt.insert(6);
            bt.insert(20);
            bt.insert(7);

            bt.size().should.equal(10);

            bt.remove(8);
            bt.remove(18);
            bt.remove(20);

            bt.size().should.equal(7);
        });
    });

    describe('#isEmpty()', () => {
        it('returns true if tree is empty, false if not', () => {
            var bt = new BinaryTree();
            bt.isEmpty().should.equal(true);

            bt.insert(5);
            bt.isEmpty().should.equal(false);

            bt.remove(5);
            bt.isEmpty().should.equal(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `bt.root`?

Comment: Just tried this in Edge with the class only having a constructor and after creating a new BinaryTree root is null. What environment are you in? Browser? Node? What versions?

Comment: @Ryan O'Hara What does it mean? Can you explain, pls?

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren
I use atom as node. And test in mozilla firefox browser with last update. I tryed to create new js file and create class only with constructor. It doesn't help me

Comment: The "assigns null to root" test works fine for me in the latest Firefox Developer Edition as well (though executed manually, not tried it with jasmine). Do as Ryan says and add some logging to your tests to see what really happens, if you don't know about logging and debugging in javascript you should probably read up a bit on that first.